# systemctl sleep causes crash

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, suspend, 21.04

(Kubuntu 21.04)

when i suspend my laptop using a normal suspend it:

1. causes a brutal logout (crash to black screen then to login screen) when on desktop
2. causes a black screen hang on switch user (have an unrelated startup message 'SGX disabled by BIOS' with the timestamp), then eventually just turns off
3. same as 1, using `systemctl suspend` in no GUI mode on the login screen (control+alt+f2)

it sleeps completely fine using `pm-suspend` command whether logged in on desktop or in control+alt+f2 mode
but when waking up from that using the power button my computer, it wakes up and works for a brief moment, then causes a black screen similar to 2. (i suspect it's trying to suspend using systemctl) along with various nvidia graphics driver related issues then just locks up.

it was working normally before but i did an apt-upgrade, which upgraded the kernel as well as tweaking a bunch of system settings especially fiddling the screen locking settings in the control panel. I have noticed the control panel is rather buggy and doesn't save all of the settings so im a little suspicious about it, but a few ripgreps on my .config directory dont reveal much about screen locking.

so far I've tried:

- resetting settings to default on screen locking
- booting into the older the kernel and uninstalling nvidia-driver

I suspect there is something hooking onto `systemctl suspend` causing this to happen, either a process or a misconfiguration, is there a way i can make my system use pm-utils related commands instead for sleeping and resuming?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as the OP, on Ubuntu 18.04, with the same suspicions that there's some hook on suspend that's the issue. Purging the nvidia drivers didn't work for me, and this issue started occurring after updating packages which included newer nvidia drivers.

My "temporary" fix at the moment is to suspend via calling a `sleep.sh` script

```
sudo sleep 0.1  # To get auth
gnome-screensaver-command -l  # to enable lockscreen when resuming
sleep 3
echo mem | sudo tee /sys/power/state
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve this by purging the nvidia drivers.

`apt remove nvidia-driver-*` is too gentle, i tried this above and it did not work, however

`apt purge nvidia*` and `apt remove *nvidia*` fixed the problem. I suspect using nvidia-driver-460 or nvidia-driver-465 might be more stable, but im happy with my system right now, i'll try that out later if i feel like i need to.